# Variety causing 18.04 to freeze login?

Tags: gnome, login, 18.04, desktop-background, variety

I have been a fan of Variety wallpaper changer, however, installing it on 18.04 LTS has been causing problems.

When Variety is scheduled to run at startup, every now and then it freezes the login to Gnome after reboot, whether its X.org or Wayland. Using the latest Variety from the repositories.

Anyone encountering similar issues?

Comment: Variety runs here on 18.04LTS without issues. Do you have conflicting programs installed?

Comment: What are you using, Xorg or Wayland?

Comment: I can verify the same issue exists for variety, wallch and other wallpaper changers I have tested. If you logout and select the unity shell you will not have these issues (at least with wallch). This is a gnome shell problem. I've tried wallch with and without java and javascript, no change.

Comment: Any solution? I have the same problem